# Bootstrap Center Badge Text on Mobile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am using a Badge element reactstrap in a react project.

```
 <Badge color="info">{item.price + "$"}</Badge>
```

The text in the Badge is not vertically aligned centered, only on a mobile.
It is working well on pc chrome when changing the view to mobile in the inspect, but only on the actual mobile device the text is not centered.

I tried vertically-align middle and align-items center and others but in vain

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not sure but try this :

**In your css file**

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     .parentElement .badge {
       display: inline-flex !important;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;   
     }
   }
```

Specify the parentElement

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but It did not work

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to override bootstrap badge class.
The original badge class has the property "vertical-align: baseline".
In your custom css override the .badge class and set "vertical-align: text-top !important" or "vertical-align: middle !important" which suits your design..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this did not work